# Java, Reading objects from a file and adding them to an arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a Client class with two instance variables: firstName and surname

Now, I have another class in which I want to read names from a text file and store them in the Client ArrayList

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Arraylists
{
  public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

     List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();


     try
     {

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\InputTest.txt")); 


     String fileRead = br.readLine();   


            while (fileRead != null)
            {

                String[] tokenize = fileRead.split("\\n");

                String tempFirstName = tokenize[0];
                String tempSurname = tokenize[0];

                Client tempObj = new Client(tempFirstName, tempSurname);

                clients.add(tempObj);

                fileRead = br.readLine();
            }


            br.close();
        }


        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }

        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }


        for (Client client : clients)
        {
            System.out.println(client);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Now this is what I'm getting when I run the main method:

John Smith John Smith

Mike Goldman Mike Goldman

Emma Stone Emma Stone

What am I doing wrong? My text file is just a list of the above names and I want the first name and the surname to be stored as a separate pieces of information so that when I print, it prints firstName + surname for every single person in my text document

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well the fact that you're using `tokenize[0]` for both the first name and the surname doesn't help. Have you debugged into your code to work out where the problem is? Step through your code line by line, and pay careful attention to what the result is for each line - where does it not meet your expectations?

Comment: (Hint: you've got a single line, but you're trying to split it by a line break. How do you expect that to actually split anything?)

Comment: thanks guys ! see my below code, it seems like the it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] tokenize1 = fileRead.split("\\s+");
String tempFirstName = tokenize1[0];
String tempSurname = tokenize1[1];
```